# how to use webmethod on webform in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webmethod

I have a user control on my web form which is as follows
[image]

I select the program year, category type , category and position group and then click search, it should return a collection which contains the programyearID, categorytypeID and positionGroupID for the corresponding selected items in the dropdownlist and pass it on to a webmethod which is already defined to get a specific certificationID.

Interface

```
Namespace SI.Certification.UserControl
    Public Interface IUserSearchResultList
         Property DataSource() As User.Learning.Business.HR.UserCollection
         ReadOnly Property List() As User.Web.UI.WebControls.PagedRepeater
    End Interface 
End Namespace
```

here is this the code for my usercontrol1.vb

```
  Public Class curriculum_search
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
    Implements IUserSearchResultList

  Private _dataSource As UserCollection

  Public Property DataSource As UserCollection Implements UserControl.IUserSearchResultList.DataSource
        Get
            Return _dataSource
        End Get
        Set(value As UserCollection)

        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property List As PagedRepeater Implements UserControl.IUserSearchResultList.List
        Get
            Return ctlListControl
        End Get
    End Property

 #Region  "Public Properties"
 Public Property ProgramYearID() As Int32
        Get
            If Me.ShowProgramYearSearch Then
                If Me.lstProgramYear.SelectedValue = 0 Then
                    Return Integer.MinValue
                Else
                    Return Me.lstProgramYear.SelectedValue
                End If
            Else
                If ViewState("ProgramYearID") Is Nothing Then
                    Return Integer.MinValue
                Else
                    Return ViewState("ProgramYearID")
                End If
            End If
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Int32)
            If Me.ShowProgramYearSearch Then
                Me.lstProgramYear.SelectedValue = Value.ToString()
            End If
            ViewState("ProgramYearID") = Value
        End Set
    End Property

 Public ReadOnly Property CategoryTypeID() As Int32
        Get
            If Me.lstCategoryType.SelectedValue = 0 Then
                Return Integer.MinValue
            Else
                Return Me.lstCategoryType.SelectedValue
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

 Public ReadOnly Property CategoryID() As Int32
        Get
            If Me.lstCategory.SelectedValue = 0 Then
                Return Integer.MinValue
            Else
                Return Me.lstCategory.SelectedValue
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

 Public Property PositionGroupID() As Int32
        Get
            If Me.ShowPositionCodeSearch Then
                If Me.lstPositionGroup.Selected = -1 Then
                    Return Integer.MinValue
                Else
                    Return Me.lstPositionGroup.Selected
                End If
            Else
                If ViewState("PositionGroupID") Is Nothing Then
                    Return Integer.MinValue
                Else
                    Return ViewState("PositionGroupID")
                End If
            End If
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Int32)
            If Me.ShowPositionCodeSearch Then
                Me.lstPositionGroup.Selected = Value.ToString()
            End If
            ViewState("PositionGroupID") = Value

        End Set
    End Property

Public Property ShowPositionCodeSearch() As Boolean
        Get
            If ViewState("ShowPositionCodeSearch") Is Nothing Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return ViewState("ShowPositionCodeSearch")
            End If
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
            ViewState("ShowPositionCodeSearch") = Value
            If Not Value Then
                spnPositionGroup.Visible = False
            Else
                spnPositionGroup.Visible = True
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

 Public Property ShowProgramYearSearch() As Boolean
        Get
            If ViewState("ShowProgramYearSearch") Is Nothing Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return ViewState("ShowProgramYearSearch")
            End If
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
            ViewState("ShowProgramYearSearch") = Value
            If Not Value Then
                spnProgramYear.Visible = False
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
   #End Region

   #Region "Events"
    Public Event Submit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load, Me.Load

        If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
            If spnCategoryType.Visible = True Then
                BindCertificationCategoryTypeCollection()
            'method to bind the category collection
            End If
            If spnProgramYear.Visible = True AndAlso Me.ShowProgramYearSearch Then
                BindProgramYearCollection(GetProgramYearCollection())
            'method to bind the porgram year collection
            End If
            If spnPositionGroup.Visible = True AndAlso Me.ShowPositionCodeSearch Then
            End If
            lstPositionGroup.DefaultToPrimary = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles pnlSearch.SearchClick
        RaiseEvent Submit(sender, e)
    End Sub
```

This is the webmethod I have to use in my usercontrol to pass the parameters

```
 <WebMethod(Description:="Get list of certification levels")> _
 Public Function GetCertificationLevelsList(ByVal programYearId As Integer, ByVal PositionGroupId As String, ByVal CategoryId As
String) As User.Department.Application.Curriculum.Items
     Dim items As User.Department.Application.Curriculum.Items =  User.Department.Application.Curriculum.CategoryCollection.GetCategoryLevelsList(programYearId,
PositionGroupId, CategoryId)
     items.Sort()
     Return items
 End Function
```

I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use webmethods on Usercontrols. Webmethods must live on webpages. Since UserControls can live on multiple pages, you can't put a webmethod in a codebehind page of a UserControl.

So your options are:

- Create an .asmx for your webmethod and call it from your webcontrol (old-skool)
- Create a WCF enpoint (.svc) and call it from your webcontrol (semi-old-skool)
- Create a WebAPI Controller and call it from your webcontrol (new-skool)

However, what you want to do is to call the webservice from the code-behind of your usercontrol. If you want to do this, you're mixing server-side and client-side. Your asmx is there to be used from the client-side. You will either need to copy the code from the asmx, or provide an abstraction that can be used in both the webservice and the usercontrol.

Comment: You're mixing server-side and client-side. It's no use to call a local webservice from the server-side. The asmx is there to be called from the client-side. You can either copy the code from the asmx to the submit method, or abstract the method to some shared location.

Comment: can you pls provide an example?